# Same app paid for twice due to some error on Google Play Store, no receipt of failed transaction, but money deducted

Tags: google-play-store, paid-apps, google-play-games

I purchased a game yesterday, however due to some issue the purchase failed, yet the amount was deducted. I contacted the bank and they registered my complaint and informed me that either I'll receive the money back or the merchant will. Being impatient I purchased the same game later, but my previous transaction was also sent to the merchant, which I found out when I enquired the status of my complaint with the bank. Now I have no idea how to resolve this, I have not received any receipt for the previous transaction as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- As updated by OP the first payment has been cancelled after verifying in the [payments Center](https://payments.google.com/payments/u/0/home#)
- Since the payment had been honoured by the bank prior to the cancellation (likely), you can contact Google and [talk to them](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7100415?ref_topic=3364672&visit_id=1-636537524125763390-3549050655&rd=1) and request for a refund (or from the Google Play Settings → `Help and feedback`)
- Typical [refund requests time line here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6319938?visit_id=1-636537524125763390-3549050655&p=refund_time&rd=1)

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps provided by Google support on [how to request a refund](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2479637?hl=en).

Here's what you got to do:

1. Open [play.google.com/store/account](https://play.google.com/store/account) in a browser
2. Find the app in your purchased list,
3. Press on the three dots found to the right of the app name.
4. Press on, *report a problem*
5. In the drop down list, pick *I purchased this but did not receive it*
6. It will give you an option to describe the issue in full detail.
7. After filling in as many details, press *submit*

If however the app doesn't appear in the purchased list, use Google's page for reporting unrecognized charges, as they don't seem to havea double charge page.

Go to [this page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/contact/play_unrecognized_charge) and fill out the necessary info.