# During purchase money is deducted but the payment status is shown as cancelled-Tinder gold

Tags: google-play-store, google, google-play-services, in-app-purchase

If during purchase money is deducted but the payment status is shown as cancelled will the deducted amount be refunded automatically?It happened with me while purchasing Tinder gold and after my money got deducted the interface shown some error and shown the transaction cancelled and  the status of transaction is also shown as cancelled in the Google payments history.

Comment: See the time line for refund mentioned here https://android.stackexchange.com/a/190765/131553